# CakePHP chain custom finder with OR condition

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

How to chain custom finders with `OR` condition?
I have a `beforeFind()` method where I check permissions.

```php
if (isset($access->corporate)) {
    $query->find('forCorporate', ['corporate_id' => $access->corporate]);
}
if (isset($access->company)) {
    $query->find('forCompany', ['company_id' => $access->company]);
}
```

I would need to chain the 2 finders above with an OR condition to the original query.

Comment: You actually need to check the permissions at: https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/policies.html#policy-scopes

Comment: @Salines I may use it there, but the problem is the same. Chaining with OR

Comment: How looks your finder queries?

Comment: @Salines like this. 
public function findForCorporate(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        return $query->where(['corporate_id' => $options['corporate_id']);
    }

Comment: try with Combinators https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions

Comment: Yep it seems I can not do it with custom finders. I think using query expressions is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and post here hoping it can help others.

First of all, I needed clean copies of the query to create subqueries without ending up in an infinite loop. There I removed all previous `WHERE` conditions.

Then I called `where()` to the original query using a callback method. This gave me the access to manipulate the `QueryExpression`.

As I wanted to chain the custom finder queries with `OR` condition I needed a starting condition, what always false, that is why I have `1 = 0` condition. Then I was able to use the `QueryExpression`'s `add()` method to chain the queries.

```php
$cleanQueryCorporate = $query->cleanCopy()
    ->select(['Accounts.id'])->where(null, [], true);
$cleanQueryCompany = $query->cleanCopy()
    ->select(['Accounts.id'])->where(null, [], true);

$query->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) use ($access, $cleanQueryCorporate, $cleanQueryCompany, $options) {
    $exp = $exp->or('1 = 0');       // this needed to add the next ones with OR
    if (isset($access->corporate)) {
        $exp = $exp->add(['Accounts.id IN'=> $cleanQueryCorporate
            ->find('forCorporate', ['corporate_id' => $access->corporate])]);
    }
    if (isset($access->company)) {
        $exp = $exp->add(['Accounts.id IN'=> $cleanQueryCompany
            ->find('forCompany', ['company_id' => $access->company])]);
    }
    return $exp;
});
```